# Lollipop Update Issue: Google Apps

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g

I'm using a Moto G 2nd Gen, and I have recently updated to the new lollipop version. In the last day, I've had to restart the phone a dozen times, as after being powered on, it becomes completely unresponsive in about 10-20 minutes. None of my Google Apps work, the phone freezes, and it is impossible to use.

I wanted to do a factory reset but it won't even allow me to transfer or backup my recent files. It just freezes.

I've seen a few other questions with this issue, does anyone know any fixes?

edit: it occasionally gives me the notification "Google Apps is not responding" but I can't do anything as the screen is unresponsive.

Comment: As for Backup, you might wish to check with [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/16575) (and our [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info). Concerning the Google apps, you could try to clear their cache and, if that doesn't help, delete their data (via *Setup › Apps › All*, picking each related entry). [Safe mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info) might help with that, if the device otherwise reboots too fast to get you done.

Answer (score 0):

Boot to recovery, and remove gapps manually. You can also backup apps and their settings using `adb backup -all -apk -nosystem`

Comment: Uh. That would at least require the device to be rooted – which the OP didn't indicate having done (GApps are installed as system apps).